# Print alphabets and numeric given in one string separately in java

Tags: java, string

Given a string with alphabetical, numeric, and special characters - for example `String s= "abc12$%"` - print the alphabetical, numeric and special characters separately. ***Without changing the string into character!***

Answer:

```
Alphabet: abc
numeric: 12
special character: $%
```

Help me with the Java code..

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a homework question. If not, see here for how to ask a good question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to show code for what you've already attempted not just ask for solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show much effort here, but `String#replaceAll` is well-suited to this problem.  We can try removing classes of characters which don't match what we want to target.

```
String input = "abc12$%";
System.out.println("alphabet: " + input.replaceAll("(?i)[^A-Z]+", ""));
System.out.println("numeric: " + input.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", ""));
System.out.println("symbol: " + input.replaceAll("(?i)[A-Z0-9]+", ""));
```

This prints:

```
alphabet: abc
numeric: 12
symbol: $%
```

Here is an explanation of the regex patterns used above.  Note that we replace with empty string in all cases, so we are matching what we want to *remove*.

```
(?i)[^A-Z]+    match any non letter, case insensitive (?i)
[^0-9]+        match any non digit
(?i)[A-Z0-9]+  match any alphanumeric character (i.e. a letter or number)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm just learning java. It worked.. But Could you please explain the logic in replace all. _(?i)[^A-Z]_, _[^0-9]_ , 
_(?i)[A-Z0-9]_  what does this logic means?

Comment: I'm new to this website. i created account an hour before.. I'm sorry.. I'm learning to use these options now only..

Answer (score 0):

This is a logical question, so I prefer only to give idea instead of exact solution.

Try this:

read the ASCII value of each character in string, analyze which character falls in which range of ASCII values, add each character in 3 different array each for alphabet, number and special character, and finally print all the array in string.

Comment: I think that violates the "without changing into character" (artificial/homework) limitation